# How to recognize data format

Tags: json, xml, dataformat

I have same type of data in two format but I not sure which format they are.

Data format 1

```
{
  "ArraytionGroup": {
    "-xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
    "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "LocationGroup": [
      {
        "Id": "6",
        "Uuid": "894055b6-971ecc0c7224",
        "Name": {
          "-xmlns": "http://www.air-watch.com/servicemodel/resources",
          "#text": "gtg"
        },
        "GroupId": { "-xmlns": "http://www.air-watch.com/servicemodel/resources" },
        "LocationGroupType": {
          "-xmlns": "http://www.air-watch.com/servicemodel/resources",
          "#text": "C"
        },
        "Country": {
          "-xmlns": "http://www.air-watch.com/servicemodel/resources",
          "#text": "s"
        },
        "Locale": {
          "-xmlns": "http://www.air-watch.com/servicemodel/resources",
          "#text": "kk"
        },
        "ParentLocationGroup": {
          "-xmlns": "http://www.air-watch.com/servicemodel/resources",
          "-uuid": "bdce439362",
          "#text": "70"
        },
        "CreatedOn": {
          "-xmlns": "http://www.air-watch.com/servicemodel/resources",
          "#text": "2/21/2018 3:08:55 PM"
        },
}
```

Data format 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SarttGroupSe xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.air-watch.com/servicemodel/resources">
    <Page>0</Page>
    <PageSize>500</PageSize>
    <Total>61</Total>
    <LocationGroups>
        <Id xmlns="">655</Id>
        <Name>EDX</Name>
        <GroupId>DDDD</GroupId>
        <LocationGroupType>Container</LocationGroupType>
        <Country/>
        <Locale/>
        <Users>0</Users>
        <Admins>0</Admins>
        <Devices>0</Devices>
    </LocationGroups>
    <LocationGroups>
        <Id xmlns="">2</Id>
        <Name>EE</Name>
        <GroupId>New</GroupId>
        <LocationGroupType>C</LocationGroupType>
        <Country/>
        <Locale/>
        <Users>0</Users>
        <Admins>0</Admins>
        <Devices>0</Devices>
    </LocationGroups>
    <LocationGroups>
        <Id xmlns="">6</Id>
        <Name>RAC</Name>
        <LocationGroupType>Ciner</LocationGroupType>
        <Country/>
        <Locale/>
        <Users>0</Users>
        <Admins>0</Admins>
        <Devices>0</Devices>
    </LocationGroups>
</SarttGroupSe>
```

What format these data can anyone help me out?

Comment: First json second xml

Comment: @pc_coder - If you are very sure. Write it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON objects are surrounded by curly braces {}.

JSON objects are written in key/value pairs.

Keys must be strings, and values must be a valid JSON data type (string, number, object, array, boolean or null).

example  `{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }`
then your first example is a json object 
validate your first example in [json validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

The Element object represents an element in an XML document. Elements may contain attributes, other elements, or text. If an element contains text, the text is represented in a text-node.

example `<year>2005</year>` then your second example is a xml object

try your second example in [xml validator](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)